# Symfony2, twig and JavaScript

Tags: php, symfony, twig

What do I need to do to get twig to process a JavaScript file?  I have an html.twig that uses a JavaScript twig.  Something like this:

```
{% extends 'BaseBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% javascripts
        '@BaseBundle/Resources/js/main.js.twig'
    %}
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}

< more template omitted >
```

And parts of main.js.twig:

```
function testFunction()
{
    alert('{{VariableFromPHP}}');
}
```

And the controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/",name="home")
 * @Template("MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
   return array( 'VariableFromPHP' => 'Hello World');
}
```

I expected the JavaScript to look like this at run-time:

```
alert('Hello World');
```

But, the code is unchanged.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assetic does not include twig templates; you should create a separate controller for the javascript file. Although I would consider it bad practice performance-wise, because you will have to process two requests this way.

```
/**
 * @Route("/main.js")
 */
public function mainJsAction() {
    $params = array( 'test' => 'ok' );
    $rendered = $this->renderView( 'MyBundle:Default:main.js.twig', $params );
    $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response( $rendered );
    $response->headers->set( 'Content-Type', 'text/javascript' );
    return $response;
}
```

```
{% extends 'BaseBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ path('my_default_mainjs') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

An alternative is to dump dynamic variables in the html, and only use static javascript files.

Answer (score 18):

My sugestion to use global variables:

```
{% javascripts '@AcmeBundle/Resources/public/js/*' output='js/compiled/main.js'%}
        <script>
            var TWIG = {};
            TWIG.variableOne   = "{{ path('rote_to_nowhere') }}";
            TWIG.variableTwo   = "{{ helloworldVar }}";
            TWIG.variableThree = "{{ "something"|trans }}";
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

then you can use it in your `js` file:

```
alert(TWIG.variableTwo);
```

Comment: This is perfect for what what I need, routes generated for use in ajax queries.

Comment: Possibly using `var TWIG = TWIG || {};`, especially when you are planning on using this twice.

Comment: @LaytonEverson The [FosJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) can help you with that

Answer (score 1):

Instead, what I did is this in the main.js:

```
function doGetStringFromSubClass()
{
    if (typeof getStringFromSubClass == 'function')
    {
        return getStringFromSubClass();
    }
    else
    {
        alert('getStringFromSubClass() needs to be defined.')
    }
}

function testFunction()
{
    alert(doGetStringFromSubClass());
}
```

and, in the subclass twigs, we have this main.js:

```
function getStringFromSubClass(){
    return "baseClassString";
    }
```

And this twig:

```
{% extends 'BaseBundle:Default:index.html.twig' %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}

    {% javascripts
        '@SomeSubclassBundle/Resources/js/main.js'
    %}

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Kinda goofy, but, it works.

Scott