# Renedering a twig template from Angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, twig

I'm trying to generate a twig template which is a modal through AngularJs. But, my modal doesn't show up, it just calls for a 404 request that appears in my debug tool (No route found for "GET /en/admin/payments/views/viewServiceStatus". I don't know what the problem is. This is the angular directive.

```
app.directive('viewServiceStatus', [function() {
return {
restrict: 'E',
scope: {
  model: '=',
},
link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
  scope.$watch('model.visible', function(newValue) {
    var modalElement = element.find('.modal');
    modalElement.modal(newValue ? 'show' : 'hide');
  });

  element.on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    scope.$apply(function() {
      scope.model.visible = true;
    });
  });

  element.on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    scope.$apply(function() {
      scope.model.visible = false;
    });
  });

},
templateUrl: 'views/viewServiceStatus',
 };
}]);
```

This is my route.yaml file

```
acme_bundle_service_status:
path: views/viewServiceStatus
defaults:
    _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
    template:    '@PaymentBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Payment/viewServiceStatus.html.twig'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2, twig and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572506/symfony2-twig-and-javascript)

Comment: @brokleyscoding You should be able to see failed request in you `Network` console in Debug tool. Which path does it call? I would assume `myappsdomain.com/app_dev.php/views/viewServiceStatus`...

Comment: Yes this is the path and by error, I meant this error appears in my debug tool.

Comment: try with `templateUrl: '/views/viewServiceStatus',`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with

```
`templateUrl: '/views/viewServiceStatus',`
```

instead of

```
`templateUrl: 'views/viewServiceStatus',`
```

Hope this help